# Save and export EER diagram layout in Mysql Workbench

Tags: sql, layout, mysql-workbench, entity-relationship

I am using Mysql Workbench to design a database in one of my projects. My initial goal was to find a way to manage the versions of the `.mwb` file (Mysql workbench file) with git, but I don't think this is possible since `.mwb` files are binary files.

Then I had another idea. Instead of managing the `mwb` file, I could manage the database creation script written in `sql` and exported by Mysql Workbench, and as an `sql` file contains text, git is able to manage its versions ! However, I found another problem: when you get the updated `sql` file and import it in Workbench, the EER diagram is not recovered and you always have to recreate it (under the menu Model-->Create diagram from catalog objects), and the layout of the former diagram is actually lost.

So, is it possible to save and export the layout of the diagram from Mysql workbench ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: MySQL Workbench models are not made to be version controlled.

Long answer: a model (.mwb) file is just a zip of the model xml (a streamed-out document of the in memory GRT tree, which contains all design information) + some additional stuff like attached scripts/notes and test data defined in the Inserts Tab in the table editor (an sqlite DB). The main problem here is that WB does not save an xml, but an mwb file. So, if you put that xml in your git repo, you would constantly have to extract it from the mwb, which is why it's indeed almost impossible to put a model file under version control.

Comment: Okay thank you. So basically, if I want to get the `XML` file from the model, I will have to change the extention of the file from `mwb` to `zip`and extract the archive which contains it. Now, isn't there a way to automate that procedure by writing some script ?

Comment: That's one step, yes, but you also need to get the xml back into a model file. Originally models were just xml files and WB could import them. But IIRC that is no longer possible.